# How to add image to the user interface in Minecraft 1.8?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I found in a [forum](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-mods/1288584-stadiametric-bow-scope) a texture to add Stadiametric in Minecraft as you can see below.

[image]

According to the article, the image must be renamed to "pumpkinblur.png" and must be inserted in the "misc" folder of a texture pack. I followed the instructions exactly but the image is not added to Minecraft. I'm using version 1.8 of the game. How can I add this image to my interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "pumpkinblur.png" file is the image that overlays your HUD (in first person view) when you wear a pumpkin on your head.

[image]

In resource packs, it's not uncommon to replace this with another image, especially when the view is so restrictive. I.e.:

[image]

So basically, this image is only relevant when you have a (sheared?) pumpkin on your head.